# Excel File not downloading using AJAX in MVC4

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a MVC4 application and trying to create a Excel file by making use of RDLC reports. Following is the AJAX code I have written to make a call to the controller method.

```
var actionUrl = '@Url.Action("MethodName", "ControllerName")';
 $.ajax(actionUrl, {
        type: 'POST',
        data: { merchantAlias: merchantName2, merchantName: merchantName1, sDate: date1, eDate: date2, Incident: whichIncident, call: whichcall },
        success: function (d) {
           alert(d);
           alert("success1");
       }
});
```

I tried debugging the application and verified that the controller method is called properly and it is returning the File. It also shows the "success" alert message, **however on the view the file is not getting downloaded.**

I tried similar thing using an hyperlink and sent hard coded parameters to the method and the file is getting downloaded. Following is the code:

```
<div><a href="@Url.Action("MethodName", new { merchantAlias = "someAlias", merchantName = "someName", sDate = "2015-01-01 00:00:00", eDate = "2015-01-01 00:10:00", Incident = "0", call = 1 })"> Get Report Excel</a></div>
```

But I need to pass dynamic parameters to my method based on the selection made by user on the view.

Following is the code written inside Controller Method:

```
        LocalReport lr = new LocalReport();
        lr.ReportPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports"), "MerchantExcelReport.rdlc");
        DataTable dt = GetDataForExcel(merchantAlias, merchantName, sDate, eDate, Incident, call);
        ReportDataSource rd = new ReportDataSource("MerchantExcelDataSet", dt);
        lr.DataSources.Add(rd);
        string reportType = "Excel", mimeType, encoding, fileNameExtension;

        string deviceInfo =
        "<DeviceInfo>" +
        "  <OutputFormat>" + reportType + "</OutputFormat>" +
        "  <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" +
        "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" +
        "  <MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop>" +
        "  <MarginLeft>1in</MarginLeft>" +
        "  <MarginRight>1in</MarginRight>" +
        "  <MarginBottom>0.5in</MarginBottom>" +
        "</DeviceInfo>";

        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streams;
        byte[] renderedBytes;

        renderedBytes = lr.Render(reportType, deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streams, out warnings);
        return File(renderedBytes, mimeType);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the file is not getting downloaded"? Ajax calls download data from the server but does not cause the download file prompt to be displayed to the user. You can get the file contents In the success method I guess.

Comment: If this is the case, instead of a JSON post request, simulate a hyperlink click,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With ajax you cannot download the file you can use

```
window.location = 'your url';
```

Or use can use

[jQuery File Download plugin](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/) to download file what you need to do is return file path from your controller and on sucess of ajax call

```
var actionUrl = '@Url.Action("MethodName", "ControllerName")';
 $.ajax(actionUrl, {
        type: 'POST',
        data: { merchantAlias: merchantName2, merchantName: merchantName1, sDate: date1, eDate: date2, Incident: whichIncident, call: whichcall },
        success: function (d) {

           $.fileDownload(yourfilepath);
       }
});
```

Comment: I made use of window.location

Answer (score 0):

You can not make browser prompt to download file with ajax. You have to store your file some where on your server and then have to set window.location with file path.

Or if you want to use stream instead of storing file, simply put the url of your code which is returning file rather any ajax request with your query string parameters.